# Can host aliases be assigned to deployments in Kubernetes? If so, how?

Tags: internal-dns, kubernetes, hosts, google-kubernetes-engine

This [article](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/add-entries-to-pod-etc-hosts-with-host-aliases/) describes how to assign host aliases to pods in kubernetes, is there anyway to do it for a deployment and not for a pod as such?

Any other suggestions to add host entries in kubernetes to provide a first line of host name resolution (before checking a server like 8.8.8.8) would be welcomed as an answer as well.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Yes this is possible. All you need to do is follow the same advice you were for a pod specification, but rather than applying it to a YAML file for pods, you apply it to a YAML file for a deployment. 
For example, if you are already running a deployment you can edit the current deployment by issuing the following command.

$ kubectl edit deployment DEPLOYMENT_NAME

This will allow you to access edit mode of the currently running deployment in YAML format.

You need to add the 'hostAliases' section in the deployments 'template: spec' field which allows you to configure the template for the pod/containers. So to demonstrate this visually, here is the YAML for a deployment I am running in my project that I can edit by running the command I mentioned above:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  annotations:
    deployment.kubernetes.io/revision: "6"
  creationTimestamp: 2018-01-30T14:42:48Z
  generation: 7
  labels:
    app: nginx-site-app
  name: nginx-site
  namespace: default
  resourceVersion: "778922"
  selfLink: /apis/extensions/v1beta1/namespaces/default/deployments/nginx-site
  uid: dc4535333d-05cb-11e8-b5c0-7878748e0178
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx-site-app
  strategy:
    rollingUpdate:
      maxSurge: 1
      maxUnavailable: 1
    type: RollingUpdate
  template:
    metadata:
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        app: nginx-site-app
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: gcr.io/myprojectid/tuneup-nginx:latest
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        name: nginx-container
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
          protocol: TCP
        resources: {}
        terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
        terminationMessagePolicy: File
      dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
      restartPolicy: Always
      schedulerName: default-scheduler
      securityContext: {}
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30
status:
  availableReplicas: 1
  conditions:
  - lastTransitionTime: 2018-01-30T14:55:28Z
    lastUpdateTime: 2018-01-30T14:55:28Z
    message: Deployment has minimum availability.
    reason: MinimumReplicasAvailable
    status: "True"
    type: Available
  observedGeneration: 7
  readyReplicas: 1
  replicas: 1
  updatedReplicas: 1
```

If I want to add 'hostAliases' to the pods within this deployment, I need to add this information to the pod template spec section as demonstrated below (notice it is in line with 'containers' (***important- it's worth noting that there are two 'spec' sections within my file- I don't want to add it to the first spec section, but rather the template spec section which defines the pod template):

```
     spec:
       containers:
       - image: gcr.io/development-project-192309/tuneup-nginx:latest
         imagePullPolicy: Always
         name: nginx-container
         ports:
         - containerPort: 80
           protocol: TCP
       hostAliases:
       - ip: 127.0.0.1
         hostnames:
         - myadded.examplehostname
```

Answer (score 5):

`hostAliases` is part of the `PodSpec`, which is what you also find in Deployment under `spec.template.spec` in your Deployment so you can easily use it in the same way in your Deployments Pod spec template as you do for Pod it self.

Comment: I've tried doing it that way before posting here but I was unsuccessful. Would you be able to provide an example? Thank you